# k8s API server is down due to misconfiguration, how to bring it up again?

Tags: kubernetes

I was trying to add a command line flag to the API server. In my setup, it was running as a daemon set inside the k8s cluster so I got the daemon set manifest using kubectl, updated it, and executed `kubectl apply -f apiserver.yaml` (I know, this was not a good idea).

Of course, the new yaml file I wrote had an error so the API server is not starting anymore and I can't use kubectl to update it. I have an ssh connection to the node where it was running and I can see how the kubelet is trying to run the apiserver pod every few seconds with the ill-formed command. I am trying to configure the kubelet service to use the correct api-server command but am not being able to do so.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The API server definition usually lives in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` - Edit the configuration there rather than at the API level